# How to retrieve list of objects from controller using ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I want to retrieve list of objects from controller and pass it to the view using ajax. My controller's Get action's code is :

```
       public ActionResult Get()
        {
            Home h = new Home();
            return View(h.get());
        }
```

h.get() returns a list , which I want to send back to the ajax call written in the view. Ajax call :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("Get","Home")',
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        });
</script>
```

How can I transfer data from controller to view ? I need help in this , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should return the data as JSON.

```
public ActionResult Get()
        {
            Home h = new Home();
            return Json(h.get(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: I am getting this error "The name 'JSON' doensot exist in the current context" . I have added System.Web.Helpers , but it does not work

Comment: @HammadShahid change the case .. it is Json .. not JSON

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a view back in this case. You should return a JSON.

```
return Json(result, "text/html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or if you want to return a view with a model attached to it you could do

```
return PartialView("Name", model);
```

and on the view side you load it to the div

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("Get","Home")',
        }).done(function (msg) {
            $("#div-id").html(msg);
        });
```